# Unable to access the JFrog Artifactory running as Docker container on Google Cloud

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, jfrog-cli

I have a VM running on GCP and got my docker installed on it. I have NGINX web server running on it with a static reserved external/public IP address. I can easily access this site by the public IP address. Now, I have my Artifactory running on this VM as a Docker container and the whole idea is to access this Docker container (Artifactory to be precise) using the same public IP address with a specific port, say 8081. I have configured the reverse proxy in the NGINX web server to bypass the request to the internal IP address of my docker container of Artifactory but the request is not reaching to it and cannot access the Artifactory.

Docker container is running:-

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a4119d923hd8        docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:latest   "/entrypoint-artifac…"   57 minutes ago      Up 57 minutes       0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   my-app-dev-artifactory-pro
```

Here are my reverse proxy settings:-

```
server {

listen 81;

listen [::]:81;

server_name [My External Public IP Address];

location / {

proxy_pass https://localhost:8081;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using GCP to run this, I think that your issue is very simple. First, you do not have to have an Nginx in order to get to Artifactory inside a Docker container. You should be able to reach it very easily using the IP and port (for example XX.XX.XX.XX:8081) and I can see that in the Nginx configuration you are listening to port 81 which is not in use by Artifactory. I think that the issue here is either you did not allow HTTP communication to your GCP instance in the instance configuration, or you did not map the port in the "docker run" command.
You can see if the port is mapped by running the command "docker ps" and see if in the "PORTS" section there are ports that are mapped. If not, you will need to map the port (8081 to 8081) and make sure you GCP instance have HTTP traffic enabled, then you will be able to get to Artifactory with IP:PORT.